# htaccess querystring redirection

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to create a rule to my htaccess which would show my URL like:

```
https://example.com/?id=foo
```

=>

```
https://example.com/foo
```

I tried this but it's not working:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=[^&]+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}? [L,R=301,NE]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to catch the value of id with () and use it in your rewrite rule using %1

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([^&]+) [NC]
 RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}%1 [L,R=301,NE,QSD]
```

you can check your syntax with https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/